Would the two voltmeters measure the same value?

I made this problem up. The rod is moving to the left in a uniform magnetic field, would the two connected voltmeters give the same reading?
My analysis says yes. They would since the induced emf in the rod depends solely on the length of the rod contributing to the circuit and this length is the same for the two meters. But what if the voltmeter's terminals were connected between two positions at a distance less than L, where L is the width of U-shaped conductor? Would it read less than $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$? I would personally say yes to that last question since the path traversed by the current is less in that last case. Am I right?
Notes
1-The voltmeters are assumed co-planar with the rod and held in a plane perpendicular to the plane of motion.
2-The whole setup is assumed existing in  the uniform magnetic field as far as we're concerned.

Note that a voltmeter connected to the moving rod comprises a circuit on its own. The movement of the wires in the magnetic field may also contribute to what is happening, and this makes it harder to analyse. Usually the voltmeter is connected to  fixed rails so that the rod will be the only moving part. Think about what would happen if you have an inner pair of rails and an outer pair of rails.

I have added a note stating that the voltmeters somehow are held in a plane perpendicular to the plane in which the rod is moving.

If the field was uniform and extended to encompass the voltmeters, then I think you will read 0 volts on both meters. There would be no change in the integral of B field surface and hence the closed path integral of the induced E field is 0. (Faraday's Law)
If, as you drew it here, the field ends before the volt meters, then they will read differently because the change in integral of the B field surface with time will differ (the inner loop being giving a smaller change in B with time)
